# Corporate/Enterprise section

Tags: website-design, buttons, enterprise

The company I work at, we need a new home page. However, we have two different target groups. Ordinary people and professionals. But I'm torn on how to separate it. I'm toying with the idea of having a "Corporate" button that changes the entire site to focus on the corporation, and keeping the default towards the people. Thus, separating it as much as possible, but yet keeping it accessable. I've also toyed with the idea of keeping the corporate links in the footer, but I don't like the idea of placing a main navigation in the footer. To easy to miss.

Anyone got any input on this, and/or well executed examples?

Comment: How do you know you need a new homepage? How did that requirement come about? Knowing that would help with determining what the homepage needs to do.

Comment: www.mycompany.com  corp.mycompany.com  have a link to the other in both

Answer (score 2):

I'd never make any difference from the start (home page) whether the user is ordinary or professional. People don't care about your target groups, they care about your services, what can your company offer them.

You will add an extra layer of complexity to your website by designing a home page that will segregate your users and will make the Information Architecture of your web page really complicated, for you as a UX and for your developers.

I recommend you use your target groups to build "personas" and tasks for every persona.

Then it will be easier for you to know what would be your ideal home page.

Remember, people it's not interested in your target groups, not even in your company. They just want to see at a glance what solution are you offering them as a company.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many companies that use an initial "landing page" that is just a switch between the different "views" that different types of users will want to see.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPEQOQ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This is a rough idea, but it can be prettied up with nice graphics. I have made the corporate and enterprise links of equal weight, but if you have more people going into the corporate section then you might want to give that more emphasis.